# Shiny.onInput - react on every click JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, listener

probably quite easy question. I am not too familiar with Javascript embedded in Shiny items and cannot get this one right

I have a gVis table and the only way to get the row selected is to use a js listener. My listener is quite easy, assigning a row to a variable (here *sustable*)

```
  sussimilar_click <- sprintf("var sustable = chart.getSelection()[0]['row'];
   Shiny.onInputChange('sustable', sustable);")
```

what i want to achieve is to alter the table beneath - changing the value from TRUE to FALSE and the other way with every click
so i have a simple observer

```
  observe({input$sustable
    values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3] <- !values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3]
  })
```

As you might expect it changes the way i need it, but it triggers only on a value change - so if i click twice on the same item it would not fire the 2nd event.

How can i get the trigger on every click? Or maybe should i change the listener without passing the value to observer (if so, how? is there any Shiny.onInput without change?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution i use for that is to add a second input, namely `input$trigger`, which i add to the javascript part. Assigning him a random number ensures that he fires on every click and triggers the code of the observer in the server function.

```
Shiny.onInputChange('sustable', sustable);
Shiny.onInputChange('trigger', Math.random());
```

and then let the server code listen on that:

```
observeEvent(input$trigger, {
   values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3] <- !values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer combining js script with shinyjs
i added onclick event to the gvis table that reads the listener and then changes the data
to the ui:

```
useShinyjs(),
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
```

and to the server:

```
  onclick("sussimilar", {
    values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3] <- !values$datAll1[input$sustable+1,3]
  })
```

of course BigDataScientist' answer is equally good as it calls for creating another entity just as mine

note: sussimilar here is the gVisTable name, not any particular function

Comment: i highly appreciate you were also looking for an answer and also found one. Would be great if you make your answer and question reproducible. It is unknown what `jsCode` and `sussimilar` are,...

Comment: sorry. extendShinyjs(text = jsCode) is just a command you insert into UI to use extended shinyjs, i did not name anything jsCode, but from what I understand it is just syntax allowing using JS code from outside. If a JS procedure name is for example foo, so you can use jsCode$foo from R. As i said i did not use it. sussimilar is just the table I was working on. Sorry for not inserting full example, as it is a large structure and 99% of it is not relevant to the query

Comment: it was just a hint on how posts are appreciated here on SO :) If my solution works i would appreciate an upvote:). But are you actually sure you dont have JS code stored in the variable `JSCode`. Otherwise i would expect an error.

Comment: sorry, i thought accepting is upvote by the person asking. Indeed lack of JSCode caused an error after I restarted R, i safely removed the line and it still works